# Jenkins Matrix job: how to execute a step only when all the matrix is successful

Tags: jenkins, matrix

I have a Jenkins Matrix job. The build step is executed for all the matrix elements, and expected. Now I'd like to add a 2nd step or a post-build-action that executes only if all the matrix was successful.

I tried both adding a post-build-action "Execute Scripts on Matrix" and "Execute Scripts" with "If build was: SUCCESS", but both jobs are executed on each matrix element, and I'd like it to be executed only once, if and only if all the matrix elements were successful

Answer (score 2):

The post build action 'success' will work for you.

I'm not sure if you want the post-build action directly after the matrix stage or after the whole pipeline, so here is an example including both cases:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build Matrix') {
            matrix {
                agent {
                    label "${PLATFORM}-agent"
                }
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'PLATFORM'
                        values 'linux', 'windows'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Build') {
                        steps {
                            // build steps
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            post {
                success {
                    steps{
                        // steps that will execute only if the whole matrix succeed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            steps{
                // steps that will execute only if ALL stages succeed 
            }
        }
    }
}
```